# How to come up with heuristic values

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star

I'm currently studying how A-star search works. I read that heuristic value should be less than the true cost from start node to goal node. When I read and watch tutorials/examples, they always come up with a set of heuristic values corresponding to each node.

How do you come up with the heuristic value on each node?

For example, implementing A-star on a map. A map has a lot of source and destination that represent as nodes. You cannot simply add up the distances to know the true cost so you can come up with a heuristic value which is less than the true cost. It would take a lot of time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Finding a good heuristic which never over estimates the real costs is the real art. On a flat map, as in most examples, it is quite obvious that the direct distance is always shorter or equal the distance of the route which avoids obstacles. But in the real wold, finding a good heuristic is the hard part. It is worth to spend a lot of time in finding the heuristic because the better it is the faster the A-star search will be.

Comment: There's no magic answer in general.  You usually have to look for a way of relaxing the constraints of the problem that makes it (much) easier to solve.  E.g. for the 15-puzzle, if you notice that every move changes the position of only 1 tile, you can find a lower bound on the number of moves by picking some tile and counting the number of horizontal and vertical moves that would be needed to get it to the correct position, *pretending that there were no other tiles in the way*.  Since this works for *any* tile, you can do the calculation for all of them, and pick the largest.

Comment: @MrSmith42 so i guess i should do trial and error to get the best heuristic values or just add up distances and make heuristic values from them. Any good method in coming up with heuristics on maps?

Comment: @j_random_hacker i have read about 15-puzzle example that there's a number of moves that you need to count to come up with good heuristics. however, i'm working on maps. do you have suggestion or methods that i can use to get good heuristics on maps?

Comment: Just use the Euclidean distance between the endpoints, as MrSmith42 suggested.